Why is the output of this Lisp do loop different than expected?
Why is the output of this Lisp do loop different than expected?
Body:
I have the following Common Lisp code:
(setq x 10)
(setq y 30)

(do ((x       0 (+ 3 x)) 
     (y      20 (- y 2))
     (z (- y x) (- z x)))
    ((> x y) (- x y))           ; exit condition
  (format t "~% z = ~d" z))     ; print local variable Z

(format t "x = ~d y = ~d" x y)  ; print global variables X and Y

I expect the output to be:
z = 20
z = 17
z = 11
z = 2
z = -10
x = 15 y = 10

However, when I run this code, the compiler tells me this is not the correct solution. I'm confused about the following:
How are the variables x, y, and z being updated during each iteration?
Why is my expected output incorrect?
What is the correct output and why?
Could someone help me understand the flow of execution for this code and the actual output?

(graduated from SG)

You have your expected output, but what's the actual output when you run it?

If you're getting warnings about those setqs, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626097/setq-vs-undeclared-free-variable-common-lisp

See the difference between do* and do in the Common Lisp hyperspec. DO updates the variables in parallel and DO* updates the variables sequentially. See also LET and LET*.
Also: the global variables are not changed. DO creates local variables for X, Y and Z.

z = 20
z = 20
z = 17
z = 11
z = 2
x = 10 y = 30

here's the compiler output

@HasanSaafen : yes, that's expected for DO. What you expect is something like what DO* does.
